# Using StepObjects in codeception, error message: [ErrorException] Undefined variable: scenario

Tags: php, laravel-4, codeception

I'm using [codeception](http://codeception.com/) with laravel4 to test my API.
I have a set of functions that need to be used many times in different tests.
I'm trying to use StepObjects to do this.
based on an example in [this](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Cest-Classes) link
here is my code:
The code in the _steps folder

```
namespace ApiTester;
 
 class generalSteps extends \ApiTester {
 
     public function json_format( $path = "/users/me", $desc = "TEST") {
         $I = $this;
         $I->wantTo($desc);
         $I->amBearerAuthenticated(\LoginCest::$token);
         $I->sendPOST($path);
        $I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.content.data');
    } }
```

my _bootstrap.php file:

```
  \Codeception\Util\Autoload::registerSuffix('Steps',
     __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'_steps');
```

And this is how I try to access it in a function under API folder:

```
public function correct_json_format(ApiTester $I) {
       $I= new \ApiTester\generalSteps($scenario);
        $I->json_format(self::$path, "Testing the Json format for view my profile");
    }
```

when I run ./vendor/bin/codecept run api -vvv
The error That I get is :**Undefined variable: scenario**,
which is caused by this line of the code:

> $I= new \ApiTester\generalSteps($scenario);

This is the full error that I get :

> [ErrorException] Undefined variable: scenario
>
> ## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(693):
>
> PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(Codeception\TestCase\Cest))
>
> ## 1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(716):
>
> PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
>
> ## 2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Runner.php(100):
>
> PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
>
> ## 3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php(153):
>
> Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite),
> Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), Array)
>
> ## 4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(166):
>
> Codeception\SuiteManager->run(Object(Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner),
> Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), Array)
>
> ## 5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(149):
>
> Codeception\Codecept->runSuite(Array, 'api', NULL)
>
> ## 6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php(262):
>
> Codeception\Codecept->run('api')
>
> ## 7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php(191):
>
> Codeception\Command\Run->runSuites(Array, Array)
>
> ## 8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(253):
>
> Codeception\Command\Run->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(889):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Codeception\Command\Run),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/larave-codeception/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept(27):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the $scenario variable. You can get it if you add a second parameter to the function call of your CEST. It's automatically given to your test method, if you add them in the param list.

```
public function correct_json_format(ApiTester $I, $scenario) {
  $I= new \ApiTester\generalSteps($scenario);
  $I->json_format(self::$path, "Testing the Json format for view my profile");
}
```